# "outward of" or "outward from"

Tags: adverbs

I am trying to describe a positional relationship between a cylinder and a rectangular bar shown in the picture below.

After googling, I found some documents that describe this type of relationship. They say as follows:

> 1. The bar is located radially outward of the cylinder.
> 2. The bar is located radially outward from the cylinder.

Would you advise me on which is better. I understand there may be simpler ways to describe this relationship, but I would like to use the phrase "radially outward of/from".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Radially outward *from* the cylinder" is the better of the two. Radially outward is a direction, not a place. Cf. "outside."

Comment: Does "radially outside" make sense?